# Symfony2. How to ensure controller implements some method no matters if its public/private/protected and if it has any arguments?

Tags: php, symfony, interface

I wonder if I can make controllers implementing some methods no matters if that method will be **public**, **private** or **protected** and if it will have any parameter. I just want to ensure, that controller has method with specified name, no more.

For example:

```
interface SomeInterface {
  function someFunction();
  function someOtherFunction();
}

class SomeController extends SomeBaseController implements SomeInterface {
  //some action
  public function someAction() { ... }

  //an implementation of SomeInterface method
  public function someFunction() { ... }  

  //an implementation of SomeInterface method
  protected function someOtherFunction($someParameter) { ... }
}
```

I know that it's not possible to do this with ordinary php interfaces but maybe there is some other way in php or maybe symfony2 has some tool to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no way to accomplish this. So I mark my question as reslolved, however if someone knows an answer let me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know of one way to do this, which relies on the __call() method available in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

```
__call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.
```

You could go ahead and create a parent class that looks like this - although it's not an Interface, so take care if you need it outside a single domain.

```
class BaseClass{

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $methodsToImplement = array(
            'method1', 'method2', 'method3'
        );

        if (in_array($name, $methodsToImplement)) {
            throw new Exception("Method " . $name . " is not yet implemented.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it can't be an class, I have to inherit from other class and "interface" I want to create can differ for final classes (i.e. some class must implement some methods and another must implement another methods).

Although your answer is nice and might be helpful some time this is unfortunately an answer for my question.

Comment: Of cource I meant *not* an answer ;)